# How to transform XMLStreamReader to XMLStreamWriter

Tags: java, xml, io, sax, stax

Should be easy and obvious but I cant find a way - the `XMLOutputFactory` accepts anly `OutputStream`, `Result` or another `Writer` to generate a new `XMLStreamWriter`.
 What I have at hand is an `XMLStreamReader` which has no methods for extracting a `Result` or an `OutputStream`.

If the solution would be easier using the Event API, that would be OK too.

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use a `javax.xml.transform.Transformer` to convert a `StAXSource` wrapping the reader to a `StAXResult` wrapping the writer.

```
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();
StAXSource source = new StAXSource(xmlStreamReader);
StAXResult result = new StAXResult(xmlStreamWriter);
t.transform(source, result);
```

Using the Event API you could also use the folloiwng:

- http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLEventWriter.html#add(javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader)

Comment: @kostja - You may also be interested in the following method:  http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLEventWriter.html#add(javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader)

Comment: thank you, that's what I ended up using - the add() - methods of the `XMLEventWriter` are so much more comfortable and natural to use.

Comment: Could you please show or enhance the answer showing how to use `XMLEventWriter.add(XMLEventReader)` for the above purpose?